# trying to push detail view from pin annotation wont work - I am using storyboards not XIB, my detailviewcontroller IBOutlet shows as unconnected

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, mkannotation

I have a pin with disclosure button, trying to add a detail view when the button is tapped.

I am using Apple's MapCallouts as reference. I'm getting the error

> Application tried to push a nil view controller on target

using their code example -

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Am I implementing it in the wrong place? I dont know why Im getting the error.

having trouble linking everything such as #import, @class @interface @property @implementation @synthesize... don't know what does what.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

    // add a detail disclosure button to the callout which will open a new view controller page
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
}
else {
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"Current Location"];
}
return pinView;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {

id<MKAnnotation> myAnnotation = [self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view      calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
// code to show details view
MapDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MapDetailViewController alloc] init];
// Adds the above view controller to the stack and pushes it into view
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
// We can release it again, because it's retained (and autoreleases in the stack). You can also choose to autorelease it when you allocate it in the first line of code, but make sure you don't call release on it then!
[MapDetailViewController release];

}
```

Comment: post your code where you implementing this and where are assigning self.detailViewController.

Comment: in this I found from other users Dont know if its correct 
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

Comment: that is correct but make sure that your self.detailViewController is not nil

Comment: how do you mean? (I'm new to coding)

Comment: ok where are you declaring and allocating detailViewController.post the code

Comment: its in the .h of where MKMapview is placed. 

pasting the code wont let me add the comment because of multiple @ signs :S

Comment: @class MapDetailViewController;

interface LocationViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
    MapDetailViewController *detailViewController;
}


property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MapDetailViewController *detailViewController;

end

Comment: Sorted it using Alloc Init. but still the view its pushing is blank and doesnt include the information I want

Comment: @holtii, Add your code to the _question_ by clicking the "edit" link under the question (don't try to put it in comments).  Then, highlight the code in the question and click the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Can you help at all with my original question? I thought  I had fixed my problem. the disclosure button does open a new view, but its not my detail view, its a blank view, then i deleted the storyboard view and it still loads the plain black view, so obviously its not working properly

Comment: @PratyushaTerli I need help I can get a view to load but its blank, I really need to get it fixed I dont know the problem

Comment: @holtii, are you still using storyboard?  If not, then you should be creating the view controller using `initWithNibName:bundle:` (not just init).

Comment: @AnnaKarenina I am using storyboard yes :/

Comment: @AnnaKarenina I know the problem, my IBOutlet detailViewController isnt connected, Apples MapCallouts uses XIB's because I am using storyboards I dont understand, How do I connect it using storyboards :S

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't use storyboards.  You could try adding that specific query to the top of your question.  Editing will cause the question to re-appear on the main page and possibly more views.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina okay thanks anyway, I thought storyboards was the latest way to create the interface, i dont understand XIB's although I might have to create my App that way because all the tutorials I see use them